# Angular Observable returns undefined after subscribing to it

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

I work with an Nx monorepo using Angular 15 and TypeScript.
I'm trying to do a simple fetch from a public api `(url = https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2)` in my service and then log it in my console but for some reason it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

The outcome is either nothing in the console, or `undefined`. I've logged the `getUser()` method in my service and i can see that i get an Observable. I logged the `fetch()` method as well but I get nothing from it.

`data.service.ts`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../../model/User';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2`);
  }
}
```

`User.ts`

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  address: {
    street: string;
    suite: string;
    city: string;
    zipcode: string;
    geo: {
      lat: string;
      lng: string;
    };
  };
  phone: string;
  website: string;
  company: {
    name: string;
    catchPhrase: string;
    bs: string;
  };
}
```

`contact-selection.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { UnitInfo } from '../../../model/unitInfo';
import { User } from '../../../model/User';
import { DataService } from '../../../services/data/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'frontend-contact-selection',
  templateUrl: './contact-selection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-selection.component.scss'],
})
export class ContactSelectionComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetch();
  }

  constructor(public service: DataService) {
  }

  fetch() {
    this.service.getUser().subscribe((user) => {
    console.log(user);
  });
}
}
```

The strange thing is that if I create a new Angular app and test exactly the same code, it works in that app, but not in my monorepo app.
I've added the `HttpClientModule` in my `app.module.ts`, and the `DataService` in the `providers` etc.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might affect the fetch so that it works in one project but not in another? Or am I missing something in my method?

Thank you

Comment: You could pipe your HTTP request in your service and `tap` its value just to see what the actual API response is. Because, lexically speaking, your code should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my `app.module.ts` I had the below code

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ContactSelectionModule,
    SummaryModule,
    HeaderModule,
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

My `HttpClientTestingModule` was overriding the `HttpClientModule` due to the order of the modules. At the same time, `HttpClientTestingModule` is not even required to exist in the imports, so removing it completely solved it.